# grouping of ul li without creating ul and li

Tags: jquery, html

i have a data like this is a UL LI

```html
<ul>
  <li>Person 1</li>
  <li>Person 2</li>
  <li>Person 3</li>
  <li>Person 4</li>
</ul>
```

but now I am getting a Department where i need to group it by DeptName at top and then the list of Persons

like

```html
<ul>Dept 1
  <li>Person 1</li>
  <li>Person 2</li>
  Dept2
  <li>Person 3</li>
  <li>Person 4</li>
</ul>
```

without closing the ul > li in a grouping section

Comment: I didn't quietly understand, could you please give a scheme/screenshot of what you're looking for ?

Comment: So just stick a ul inside the li for each department and put the people in those sub lists...

Comment: Why are you not just using two lists of people? Can you perhaps explain why the obvious approach isn't suitable for you?

Answer (score 1):

So make sublists.  Eazy pezy.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Dept 1
    <ul>
      <li>Person 1</li>
      <li>Person 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Dept2
    <ul>
      <li>Person 3</li>
      <li>Person 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have grouping like this

```css
ul>li:first-child{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
       <li>Dept 1</li>
      <li>Person 1</li>
      <li>Person 2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Dept2</li>
      <li>Person 3</li>
      <li>Person 4</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: No you can't. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: @Rob invalid. what do you mean?

Comment: You originally had Dept 1 as a child of `<ul>` and that is not valid.

Comment: @Rob Oh yeah. I mistakenly copied the code from the question and then only realized. I think you might comment when I was editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

This might be where `<dl>` can be used.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Dept 1</dt>
        <dd>Person 1</dd>
</dl>
```

This is a "definition list". A list of definitions. The "definition term" would be Dept1. Followed by a "definition term" of Person 1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: This doesn't feel like it is really correct. Person 1 is not a definition of Dept 1. What's the advantage of using `dl` compared to `ul` which feels more semantically correct?

Comment: @Chris It's a matter of semantics though a nested `<ul>` could work but some may consider these Persons to define members of the Dept

Comment: True. I guess one man's semantics is another man's... I dunno. Its all subjective though isn't it. :)

Comment: @Chris it's not really subjective.  Semantics are related to how programs like screen readers will interact with your webpage for users who have accessibility concerns.  To them, semantic markup enabling them to use your website is a very concrete issue.

Comment: @Taplar: I appreciate that semantics are important but whether or not the members of a department is a definition of the department or not feels like it is down to the author to decide. Or are you saying that it would be absolutely incorrect to use dl/dd/dt here? (I'll admit I've never really used them myself so its a bit of an unknown area for me).

Comment: I'm not speaking to if this is the correct usage of the semantics (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#toc-dom) would be a better reference for that.  I'm just saying that the definition of what the semantics for a tag are, is not subjective.  Its defined within the html spec. @Chris